# Using strcat inside another function: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, function, fault, strcat

```
    static void foo(unsigned char *cmd)
    {
        strcat(cmd, "\r\n");
        printf("\r\nfoo: #%s#", cmd);

    }
    int main()
    {
        foo("test");
        return 0;
    }
```

Compiler says Segmentation fault (core dumped)
What is the actual problem here?

Comment: You are trying to append something to the string literal `"foo"` which cannot be modified. It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: I think this is not your real code, it's just a good MCVE. But, perhaps in your real code there is no string literal involved. Anyway, you should avoid `strcat()` unless, you just need to call it once. Building strings in c can be done much more efficiently once you *really* understand how stings are represented in the language, and what they **really** are.

Comment: On a couple of unrelated notes, you don't need to use carriage-return when printing. The compiler will make sure that the newline is converted to the correct sequence for the target platform. Also, output to `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is by default line buffered, so output is flushed on newline, which makes leading newline mostly useless.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If the OP is building a HTTP request on a non windows platform it is REQUIRED.

Answer (score 6):

You have *undefined behaviour*. You are not allowed to modify *string literals*. `cmd` points to a string literal and `strcat()` attempts concatenate to it, which is the problem.

```
  int main(void)
    {
        char arr[256] = "test";
        foo(arr);
        return 0;
    }
```

You generally need to be careful when using `strcpy()` and `strcat()` etc in C as there's a possibility that you could overflow the buffer.
In my example, I used an array size of 256 which is more than enough for your example. But if you are concatenating something of unknown size, you need to be careful.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to append something to the string literal `test` which cannot be modified. It's undefined behaviour.

You want this:

```
static void foo(unsigned char *cmd)
{
    strcat(cmd, "\r\n");
    printf("\r\nfoo: #%s#", cmd);
}

int main()
{
    char test[50] = "test";
    foo(test);
    printf("test after calling foo: %s\n", test);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C string literals (like `"test"`) are read-only arrays of characters. As they are read-only they can't be modified. As they are arrays they have a fixed size. You both try to modify the string literal, and extend it.

Answer (score 1):

Other people have explained why you cannot do this operation in place.
You have basically two options:

- Either you modify the string in place (with `realloc()` to allow you to add your suffix (`"\r\n"`). But you have to be careful and use a malloc allocated data.
- Otherwise, allocate a new string of the size of the input, plus the size of your suffix, and copy the input string and the prefix there, and return it. In that case, the caller will need to `free()` the returned string (and possibly the one passed to the function, but this would have been handled eitherway).

**Edit:** if you use a statically allocated buffer, you'll probably have to add an additional parameter to the function indicating the size of the buffer available.

Comment: Point 1 is wrong, You can definitely not `realloc` a string constant. Modify your answer before it gets downvoted. You only can `realloc` memory that has previously been allocated by `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: What I meant to say is: I don't know the behaviour at runtime, assuming the compiler lets it happen. Thanks anyway.

Comment: it's undefined behaviour. Point 1 is still misleading.

Comment: Just tried: the compiler doesn't complain (which is ok, because at that point it only gets a pointer), but it produces a segmentation fault, because the pointer was not malloc allocated.

Answer (score 0):

To work with I changed the program like:

```
static void foo(unsigned char *cmd)
{
    unsigned char local[10];
    strcpy(local, cmd);
    strcat(local, "\r\n");
    printf("\r\nfoo: #%s#", local);

}
int main()
{
    foo("test");
    return 0;
}
```